# Convert a list of key-value-pair interfaces into a single mapped type

Tags: typescript

I have a set of interfaces as so:

```
interface Foo {
    key: "fooKeyType",
    value: "fooValueType",
}

interface Bar {
    key: "barKeyType",
    value: "barValueType",
}

interface Baz {
    key: "bazKeyType",
    value: "bazValueType",
}

type FooBarBaz = Foo | Bar | Baz;
type FooBarBazKey = FooBarBaz["key"];
type FooBarBazValue = FooBarBaz["value"];
```

where `*keyType` are always const strings (so that they are valid keys), but `*valueType` are just stand-ins for what might be actual types (e.g. number, Date, custom classes, etc).

I want to convert these interfaces into a singular type map that maps key -> value, such as the following:

```
/* Can I generate this from the above? */
type FooBarBazMap = {
    fooKeyType: "fooValueType",
    barKeyType: "barValueType",
    bazKeyType: "bazValueType",
}
```

Is there a way to do this with mapped types? Mapped types don't seem to let you refer to the currently indexed type, just the type as a whole, which means you can't tie together fields from the same interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yep. It all boils down to transforming this type:

```
type KeyValue<K extends string, V> = {
    key: K,
    value: V,
};
```

...to this:

```
type Desired<K extends string, V> = {
    [key in K]: V;
};
```

Ideally, we would like to type something like this:

```
type TransformKeyValueWrong<T extends KeyValue<T["key"], T["value"]>> = {
     [key in T["key"]]: T["value"];
};
```

But typescript compiler would yell at us "[ts] Type parameter 'key' has a circular constraint.", which is true, but won't stop us, since we have generic parameter defaults!

```
type TransformKeyValue<T extends KeyValue<K, T["value"]>, K extends string = T["key"]> = {
    [key in K]: T["value"];
};
```

All we have to do now is declare intersection type for Foo, Bar, Baz:

```
type SuperDuperType =
    & TransformKeyValue<Foo>
    & TransformKeyValue<Bar>
    & TransformKeyValue<Baz>
    ;
```

Verify it works:

```
type Test = SuperDuperType["barKeyType"]; // type Test = "barValueType";
```

Note that generic parameter defaults require TypeScript version >=2.3

Comment: Thanks! Didn't think of doing this per-interface rather than unifying them first.