# Turning discriminated union into object

Tags: typescript, types, typescript2.0

Is there a way to turn a discriminated union like this:

```
type Something = {
   type: 'mode';
   values: 'first' | 'second';
} | {
   type: 'part';
   values: 'upper' | 'lower';
};
```

into

```
{
    mode: 'first' | 'second';
    part: 'upper' | 'lower';
}
```

using some generic type?

So far I tried something like this:

```
type MyUnion = {
   type: string;
   values: string;
};

type DiscUnionToObject<U extends MyUnion> = {
   [V in U['type']]: U['values']
}
```

but when I do `DiscUnionToObject<Something>` it produces

```
{
    mode: 'first' | 'second' | 'upper' | 'lower';
    part: 'first' | 'second' | 'upper' | 'lower';
}
```

I can't find a way for generic type to "understand" that `'upper' | 'lower'` are not a part of `Something` when `type` is set to `mode`.

Comment: I'm curious what the use case is for this?

Comment: Partially relevant: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44578801/convert-a-list-of-key-value-pair-interfaces-into-a-single-mapped-type

Comment: @Aaron I'm trying to write a types for `theme` function from `styled-theming` library and I stumbled upon this question in the process. I'm not sure if it can help me achieving desired effect but I was also curious if one can do something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Since Typescript 2.8** there is a possibility to "pluck out" a single components of discriminated unions:

```
Extract<P, { type: 'mode' }>;
```

And thanks to that, it is now possible to do exactly what was intended in the first place:

```
type DiscUnionToObject<U extends MyUnion> = {
    [V in U['type']]: Extract<U, { type: V }>['values'];
}
```

With this type, when we do `DiscUnionToObject<Something>`, we get what we wanted to:

```
{
    mode: 'first' | 'second';
    part: 'upper' | 'lower';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

TypeScript lacks some [type operators](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/16392) you'd need to do what you want.  You'd *like* to be able to say something like:

```
type DiscUnionToObject<U extends MyUnion> = {
  [V in U['type']]: (U & { type: V })['values']
}
```

where the `(U & { type: V })` intersection would pluck out a single element of the discriminated union.  For example, if `U` is `Something` and `V` is `part`, then we're talking about (`Something & { type: 'part' }`) which is *morally* equivalent to `{type: 'part', values: 'upper'|'lower'}`, but the compiler does not recognize this: it would have to say that `'part'&'mode'` is `never`, and that any object with a `never`-valued property is itself `never`, but neither of these reductions happen (well, not where we need it to).

So you can't do it that way.  You'd also like to be able to iterate over unions and/or intersections and map each element to produce other unions and/or intersections, sort of a more general version of mapped types.   But you can't do that either.

---

TypeScript is much better at programmatically *producing* discriminated unions than it is at programmatically *analyzing* them.  So, depending on your use case, you might be able to do the reverse of what you're asking for.  Start with the object and produce the union:

```
type SomethingObject = {
  mode: 'first' | 'second'
  part: 'upper' | 'lower'
}

type ObjectToDiscUnion<O, V = {
  [K in keyof O]: {type: K, values: O[K]}
}> = V[keyof V]

type Something = ObjectToDiscUnion<SomethingObject>;
```

You can verify that the `Something` above is the same as your original one.  Hope that helps; good luck!

Comment: Actually doing it the opposit way is also good for me! Thank you very much, especially for the second part!